# Is it possible to pass qrcode data into a browser for search query

Tags: php, qr-code

Ok hopefully this is possible.  Here's what I'm trying to accomplish.  We have a system in place that handles our IT tickets, cmdb, inventory etc...  What I've been tasked to do is Create a QR code that goes on equipment in our datacenter.  So if someone needs to quickly get information, they simply scan the bar code and it returns ip address, make, model, warranty info etc...  This part of it I've already accomplished.  I realized, I would have to make a page for each piece of equipment.  This could take a while, and I feel there is a better way.  I wrote everything in php, in the management software is a map showing how tables are connected primary keys etc.  What I'm wondering is, is there way to scan the qrcode on the device for instance its id, send that through the browser into a sql query?

Comment: please search alot, before asking any question.

Comment: just create a unique QR badge for every single piece of equipmant you want to tag. And point the code towards `http://www.example.com/info.php?id=<id>`, where `<id>` is the id of the specific piece of equipment as listed in your database. Easy does it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a URL QR like this:
the URL can carry a GET method information, for example: http://www.example.com/index.php?PartID=your_unique_id
then in your php go like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['PartID'])){
$part_id=strip_tags($_GET['PartID']);
$query="SELECT * FROM Database WHERE `part_ID`='".$part_id."'";
# get your query answer through mysqli() function
}
?>
```

Comment: Here's my query:

$query = "SELECT systeminfo.workstationid, networkinfo.ipaddress, systeminfo.workstationname, systeminfo.manufacturer, systeminfo.model, systeminfo.servicetag, resourcelocation.resourceid, resources.warrantyexpiry
    FROM systeminfo
    JOIN networkinfo
    ON systeminfo.workstationid=networkinfo.workstationid
    JOIN resourcelocation
    ON systeminfo.workstationid=resourcelocation.resourceid
    JOIN resources
    ON resourcelocation.resourceid=resources.resourceid
    where networkinfo.ipaddress = '10.1.2.102' AND warrantyexpiry IS NOT NULL";

Comment: then what are you waiting for? go on and create your qr in this way:  http://www.example.com/index.php?PartID=10.1.2.102

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a webapp to scan these qr codes.

I would send a AJAX Post request to the php server. The PHP script would then retrieve the corresponding information for the barcode ID.

If you need more help try to be a bit more specific on what you are having trouble with.

Comment: I'm using a qr code scanner app on an ipad.  Just testing things out right now, If I need something better thats not a prob.  But it seems to work for what I need.  The app works as it is now.  But its not very dynamic in the sense I have to create a separate page and sql query for each device.  Not to big of a deal, because its just a copy of another page and all I new to do is change the id in the query.  Which also leads to a ton of pages. I apologize I'm not a programmer at heart, I just know enough PHP to be dangerous.  This is just a simple app to use at work.  Im just a network engineer

Answer (score 0):

you can create qrcode that contains an URL like per example `www.mysite.com/index.php?type=inventory&id=1`

do it here:
https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/

in index.php you can retrieve your GET Variable type and id and receive your data from the database like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$_GET['type']." WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."'";
```

Comment: please note that if you put `$_GET['id']` directly in your query your code have a security hole.

Comment: yes ... you're right. This is a risk, but I want only show the procedure to get a database entry from a qrcode in the simplest way.

Comment: Not to worried about security in this sense.  Its not internet facing, and I'm statically setting allowed mac addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Javascript based QR code processor to decode the data on page, e.g.: https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode